# How to view changed files on git branch

Tags: git

When reviewing someone's code in a topic branch, I want to quickly see the work done by the developer: a `diff` of what was changed on the branch against its forked commit, but without checking out the branch or comparing to my current branch, which may be another work-in-progress topic branch or whatever.

What I usually do is fetch the topic branch, then:

1) a git log (`git log --decorate --all --oneline --graph`) and pick the first and last commits on the branch, like:

```
|  * 88aa417 (mybranch) the last commit in the topic branch
|  * ef16947 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
|  * b65ed5f xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
|  * ce67c59 the first commit in the topic branch
| /
|/
* 008483e xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

2) review the diff `git diff mybranch..ce67c59~1` page by page, which nicely lists the changes the developer has made over his fork base.

Is there a git command that can do step 1 and 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're after `git merge-base`.

```
git diff `git merge-base topic master`..topic
```

(edit: [git has shorthand for this](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html):

```
git diff master...topic
```

to show the accumulated changes on topic since its history diverged from master, and

```
git diff topic...master
```

to show the differences on the other side of the branch.)

Comment: the only problem with this is that `master` implies I have to know what branch it comes from, which may not be `master`. Bummer.

Comment: suppose there was additionally a `tryitthisway` branch off the `b65ed` commit.  What would you want for the diff base? How could any program tell?

Comment: "Given a branch `mybranch`, give me all changes introduced by the branch since its fork". This is what I need a program to do. Why would  a `tryitthisway` branch from `b65ed` commit interfere?

Comment: because any hierarchy among branches is entirely conventional, same as hierarchy among repos.  Branches aren't parented off branches, commits are parented off commits.